# Multidimensional array output by mysql show tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I will start to get te existing tables whit this query:

```
    <?php
        $tblArray = array($cvsShop01, $cvsShop02, $cvsShop03, $cvsShop04, $cvsShop05);
        $dbh = new ShopSM01DB_Mysql_Extended;
        foreach($tblArray as $table) {
            $query = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%$table%'";
            $data = $dbh->prepare($query)->execute($cvsShop01, $cvsShop02, $cvsShop03, $cvsShop04, $cvsShop05)->fetchall_assoc();
            if(!$data) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return $data;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

And its will output the following array:

```
    <?php
        [0] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_testTable (%table%)] => dc_01
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_testTable (%table%)] => dc_01_2
        )
    ?>
```

How can i read this out whit an foreach?

Comment: depends on how you're fetching the data (pdo? mysqli? `mysql_` functions?)

Comment: edited: Its will works whit mysql statments

Comment: numeric fetching instead of assoc makes it a little easier...